# camera shutter works only with live view shooting

Tags: canon-550d

i have a canon EOS 550D but when it's time to use it, the shutter stopped clicking. but when i used the live view shooting, the shutter works. did i clicked on something? or do i need some settings to reset?

Comment: It is very difficult to say, what is happening without any information about the settings you use while you try to take a photo. Can you supply more information? What have you tried? Did you try to factory reset your camera?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes with the earlier rebel series cameras, when going in and out of live view, the shutter can act *sticky*. Make sure you are in a photo mode (PASM) and that you are not using live view. If it is stuck open, try turning off the camera, switching modes, and turning back on. Let us know if this solves it.